# MongoDb Change order of array elements

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I work a lot with MongoDb Geospatial indexing, and now I am in the process of replacing the old  NoRM framework with the official 10gen C Sharp driver. The problem I am having is that for the existing data that was handled by NoRM, coordinates were in the opposite order [y,x] and it seems like the official driver doesn't like it.

So I for the existing data I have this structure:

```
{
   "Coordinates" [: 
   {
      "Longitude" : -85.68216, 
      "Latitude" : 38.221452          
   },
   //.. more coordinates
   ]
}
```

So my question is, how can I modify the order of all the elements within the array so it they look like:

```
{
   "Coordinates" [: 
   {
      "Latitude" : 38.221452,  
      "Longitude" : -85.68216               
   },
   //.. more coordinates
   ]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: "it seems like the official driver doesn't like it". Could you explain why? Because, AFAIK, the actual order doesn't matter.

Comment: Yeah, it does not work when using myCollection.Find(Query.WithinCircle(...)); I mean that it returns no results when I know it should. This does not happen when the coordinate is in the correct order [X, Y]

Comment: Indeed, I found [this quote](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing): "*In order to use the index, you need to have a field in your object that an array where the first 2 elements are x,y coordinates (or y,x - just be consistent; it might be advisable to use order-preserving dictionaries/hashes in your client code, to ensure consistency).*". In that case (I don't know about how many records we're talking), wouldn't a simple fix be to just iterate over the collection once and update each entry (to "refresh" it)?

Comment: I guess it would be okay to iterate with c sharp but I was wondering if there was like a mongodb script probably using findAndModify() or $set, I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Wild guess: `db.foo.update ({ $inc : { Latitude : 0 } }, { $inc : { Longitude : 0 } });` or something along those lines. That wouldn't actually change anything but *maybe* fix the order?

Comment: Can you paste your code using NoRM and the official driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reverse the order, you'll need to go through the entire collection and rewrite each document in the correct format.  Here's some JavaScript code to do that: feel free to season to taste.

```
XDB = db.locations;
var iter = XDB.find()

do {
    var doc = iter.next();
    var newdoc = {};
    newdoc.Coordinates = [];
    for ( var k in doc.Coordinates ) {
        var newpair = { Latitude: doc.Coordinates[k].Latitude, 
                        Longitude: doc.Coordinates[k].Longitude } ;
        newdoc.Coordinates.push(newpair);
    }
    XDB.update({_id: doc._id}, newdoc );
} while ( iter.hasNext() );
```